# Flask html templates with node.js: required is not defined

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, flask

Im making a website with heroku with python `Flask`

Now I need to connect mongodb database with javascript but it shows this error:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    <anonymous> http://mortis666stocksimulator.herokuapp.com/static/scripts/mongo.js:1
```

The javascript works before but after I added the line

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
```

It gives me the error. I tried to fix this so i created another buildpack (heroku/node.js)
[image: The buildpack]

And in my project folder I created a `package.json`

This is the content:

```json
{
    "name": "stocksimulator",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "First ever website project ",
    "author": "Mortis_666",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
      "mongodb": "^4.3"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": "16.13.1"
    }
  }
```

And it still doesnt work
Is there anyway to fix it?

### **Edit**

Guess what?
I tried to run the flask file in my **local machine**.
And it gives me the same error.(Even I've **already installed** node.js)

But when I run the `mongo.js` file individually, it doesnt gives me error! And the mongodb's function even work!

So it means that the problem **now** is not about how to install node.js in heroku. Its about how to use node.js in `flask`

My javascript file is inside the folder `static`
And I'm accessing the javascript file in html file

```html
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='scripts/mongo.js'}}"></script>
```

If you want to see the source code you can see it in [Github](https://github.com/Mortis66666/stock)

The [html template](https://github.com/Mortis66666/stock/blob/main/templates/home.html)
The [javascript file](https://github.com/Mortis66666/stock/blob/main/static/scripts/mongo.js)
The [flask file](https://github.com/Mortis66666/stock/blob/main/app.py)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the full traceback.

Comment: @Chris it is already the full traceback (required is not defined)
Probably because my heroku app doesnt have node.js so im asking a way to let the app have node.js

Comment: It appears that you're trying to use require in a script that is loaded into the browser. The browser can't use commonjs modules like this.

Comment: Do NOT keep doing what you're doing, it's very insecure! You can connect to MongoDB with Python. The reason you can't connect to mongo from the browser for several reasons; first is the MongoDB driver only works in NodeJS (the `require()` syntax for importing the module is how you can tell). Second, because your database URL would be publicly visible in the browser source, making it incredibly insecure.

Comment: @Phix yes that is what I'm thinking.
So Im looking for a way to fix it

Comment: @Soviut dont worry about that I saved my db url in heroku config vars

Comment: @Mortis_666 that will NOT secure it!!! That environment variable is being exposed publicly in order for the javascript to be able to even access it.

Comment: If I dont use javascript to connect to MongoDB how can I make the buttons in my website work?

Comment: You're building a Flask app which is server-side, you can build it like a regular server-side web application where links navigate, forms can perform GET and POST requests and the page reloads each time one of those requests happen. If you're trying to build an app that doesn't require refreshing then you need your flask app to serve up an API (often called a REST API). The frontend javascript talks to the API (the backend) and the backend talks to the database. You'll need to secure the API by having a login system that issues a token; that token then is sent on every request to the API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241527/discussion-between-mortis-666-and-soviut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do *not* need JavaScript to connect to MongoDB, you can connect to it directly from your Flask code using the MongoDB Python driver called [PyMongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Second, any environment variables passed to the frontend so they can be read by JavaScript are publicly available to anybody who views your source. This is **VERY INSECURE** and no sensitive values should every be passed this way!

Third, if you want your "refresh" button to work, you wouldn't talk to the database directly from the browser with JavaScript. Instead, the easiest thing to do would be to use JavaScript to trigger a browser refresh and refresh the whole page.

```
<button onclick="location.reload();">
```

However, if you want to only reload part of the page, the next most simple approach is to render a "partial". You'd create a new Flask route, let's say `/stocks/partial`, then use JavaScript to call it with `fetch()`, and that route would only render the part of the the template that listed your stocks. You could then use JavaScript to find where the old list of stocks was in the HTML and replace it.

Finally, the most common way this is done these days is with an API call. You'd set up a route that returns JSON data (for example `/api/stocks`). You'd then call that route with `fetch()` and take that data and use javascript, or a frontend templating library, to render the data as HTML. This is why React and Vue are popular; they're frontend template (and component) systems. You build your entire frontend with them and your Flask app becomes nothing but an API backend for the frontend to make calls to.